# SQL Server 2008 - Migrating database to new schema most efficient way?

Tags: sql-server

I'm just wondering what the opinion is on the most efficient way to migrate data to new schema in SQL server 2008. The database has 7 tables and is 8gb in size. I briefly tried using a .NET app and the entity framework but this was very very slow. 
It will need to convert GUIDs to INTs in a few places and so the relationships need to persisted. Just wondering if there is a simple way

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (SSIS), as one of it's primary functions is to support ETL workloads.

Comment: I'd use SSIS to build the tool but I'd create some mapping tables to convert from the GUID to the INT.  You can then do lookups on the mapping tables to keep the relationships.  And, once the conversion is complete, delete the mapping tables.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I've played around with SSIS a bit and it does seem to do the job. I'm struggling to find more information that covers setting up a mapping table that would hold the GUID and a newly created INT and to then use that output?

Any ideas?

Thanks again